# Problemas con .drawImage

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial para reproducir el juego de T-Rex de google pero me sale el siguiente error en la consola: juego.js:45 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D':

> **The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or
>   HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'
>       at dibujaRex (juego.js:45)
>       at principal (juego.js:64)
>       at juego.js:57**

Estuve leyendo linea por linea pero no encuentro el error.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(evento){
 if(evento.keyCode == 32){
  console.log("salta");
 }
});

var imgRex, imgNube, imgCactus, imgSuelo;

function cargaImagenes(){
 imgRex = new Image();
 imgNube = new Image();
 imgCactus = new Image();
 imgSuelo = new Image();

 imgRex.src = "img/rex.png";
 imgNube.src = "img/nube.png";
 imgCactus.src = "img/cactus.png";
 imgSuelo.src = "img/suelo.png";
}




var ancho = 700;
var alto = 300;
var canvas;
var ctx;

function inicializa(){
 canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
}




function borraCanvas(){
 canvas.width = ancho;
 canvas.height = alto;
}

var trex = {y: 250, vy: 0, gravedad: 2, salto: 28, vymax: 9, saltando: false};

function dibujaRex(){
 ctx.drawImage(imgRex,0,0,44,47,100,100,50,50);
}

function gravedad(){

}


//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
//BUCLE PRINCIPAL
var FPS = 10;
setInterval(function(){
 principal();
},1000/FPS);



function principal(){
 borraCanvas();
 dibujaRex();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>T-Rex</title>
 <script src="juego.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="inicializa();">
 <canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="300" style="border:2px solid #000000;"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

No se si la imagen tendrá relevancia pero la adjunto por las dudas:
[image: T rex]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La función `cargarImagenes()` es la que establece los valores para **imgRex**, antes de eso **imgRex** solo es `imgRex=undefined`, cunado cargas llamas a la función `Principal` la que llama a **borrarCanvas** y **dibujaRex** , esta ultima dentro llama a `drawImage` con **imgRex** como parámetro , pero no llamastes a **cargarImagenes** para que estableciera los valores de imgRex, re define **dibujaRex**:

```
function dibujaRex(){
    cargarImagenes() // para que establezca los valores de imgRex
    ctx.drawImage(imgRex,0,0,44,47,100,100,50,50);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

si no estoy mal creo que lo que te quedo mal fue
var imgRex, imgNube, imgCactus, imgSuelo;
ya que deberias haber escrito como
var img{ rex, nube, Cactus, Suelo }
asi se deberia crear el array
y para declararlo  deberia ser  img.rex y asi sucesivamente
si  no es eso lo que esta mal  espero que lo puedas solucionar.